# Django 'if and' template

Tags: python, django

I want to do the following in my django html page:

```
{% if myList|length and ifequal myValue 'somestring' %}
blah blah
{% endif %}
```

but I get the error:
**Unused 'myValue ' at end of if expression**

How can I do an If AND in a template??

Answer (score 39):

Try this:

```
{% if myList|length and myValue == 'somestring' %}
    blah blah
{% endif %}
```

Refer django documentation about use of [boolean-operators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#boolean-operators) and [complex-expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#complex-expressions) in django templates.

Answer (score 18):

Should be something like this:

```
{% if myList|length and myValue == 'somestring' %}
   blah blah
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Same as yours. I think I'm late to the party.

Comment: Sorry friend. Its just a coincidence.

Answer (score 2):

[Django docs on boolean operators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#boolean-operators)

> Should be something like this
>
> 1. view.py

```
def posts_request(request):  
    message=ApplyPost.objects.filter( blah blah)
    if message:
       return render (request,'blah.html',{'message':message})
```

> 2. blah.html

```
{% if message %}
     {% for post in message %}
          {% if post.provider %}
              ....
          {% endif %}
          {% if post.accept == True and post.provider %}
              ...
              ...
          {% endif %}
          ....You can add multiple if,elif, with Operators ....
    {% endfor %}
{% if message %}
```

> and

```
{% if a == b or c == d and e %}
```

Be aware that and has a higher order of precedence than or, and that parentheses are not possible. If required use nested blocks

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have to separate the `if` and the `ifequal` in two statements:

```
{% if myList|length  %}
     {% ifequal myValue 'somestring' %}
          blah blah
     {% endifequal %}
{% endif %}
```